# Include my PHP api on each websites

Tags: php

Hi how can I include my PHP API on each site without touching there codes and no javascript will be used.

Here is what my api does.

when they visit a page the first to show is my api(the interface that ask a user to share it's location) then after that it will redirect to the main page how can I include my api without touching there codes or touching the index.tpl/main.tpl because they used a different frameworks?

Comment: Who is "they" and what exactly would "they" need to do to include your API and which there codes [sic] can you not touch but need to? **We need more information.**

Comment: Give more specifics, please. What kind of application these other websites are using (is there any redirection, .htaccess )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to tell the HTTP server to serve your file instead of the normal index file, and then your script will redirect to the original index file or home page when you are done.

This is usually done through redirection in the `.htaccess` file.  Add this line to get your custom script to run first:

```
DirectoryIndex pre-index-script.php
```

Comment: Hi now the problem is the main page it will always redirect to the location define by my .htaccess.

Comment: @khem Yes, that is what the .htaccess file does for you.  In your script you'll have to look at the referring URL. If the referring URL is from the main site (ie, from your own domain) the script should redirect to the main page.  You probably only want people to see your script if they click on a link from another site, or type the address in the address bar, so detecting the referring url and going to the main page if the link was on the main site is probably the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little unclear, here is how I understood it:

When a new user arrives at your site, you want to display a page before they see the page they requested. But you want to do this without modifying to code of the site.

And with that assumption, my answer:

You can automatically "include" a php script at the start (or end) of any request by using the "[auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)" configuration directive. If you have access to your configuration, or possibly in a .htaccess file you should be able to add something like:

`php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/your/script.php`

Now that script will be added at the start of every request.

In that script you can check if the user is a new visitor, possibly by using a cookie or sessions, and show them to your "intro" page either with a [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect or by just displaying it and then exiting to prevent the normal page loading.

Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: When I try this one RewriteEngine on  

php_value auto_prepend_file /locnfo/loc.php this gives me an error.